# Month returns incorrect value from date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2005

Afternoon,

I have an issue with a SQL server that I could do with some help with.
When I run a select statement with a date range in the where it returns rows from the wrong date range.

e.g. If I execute the following

```
select * from theTable where startDate between '2016-09-01 00:00:00' and '2016-09-08 23:59:59'
```

I would expect rows where the `startDate` is between 1st and the 8th of September, what I am actually getting is rows with a `startDate` between 9th January and 9th August.

I have checked the language I have setup on for the datebase using:

```
select * from sys.syslanguages order by name where name = @@language
```

This returns British

DBCC useroptions returns

```
textsize             2147483647
language             British
dateformat           dmy
datefirst            1
lock_timeout         -1
quoted_identifier    SET
arithabort           SET
ansi_null_dflt_on    SET
ansi_warnings        SET
ansi_padding         SET
ansi_nulls           SET
concat_null_yields_null  SET
isolation level          read committed
```

I have checked the default language for the login and this is also British.

When I execute `print month('2016-09-01 00:00:00')`

It returns 1 and not 9.  Unless I am mistaken the date and time above should be ODBC canonical  `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)`.

Why is it printing 1 instead of 9, and more importantly how do I fix it?

Printing `@@version` returns

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5057.00 (X64) 
    Mar 25 2011 13:33:31 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

Thank you for your help.
If this has already been answered can you point me at it, only I cannot find the answer.

Comment: Use an unambiguous format (`YYYYMMDD`): `where startDate >= '20160901' and startDate < '20160909'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would appear to have a relatively unusual internationalization setting, where the default is YDM rather than YMD.

You can always use dates without hyphens:

```
select *
from theTable
where startDate >= '20160901' and
      startDate < '20160909';
```

These are *always* interpreted as YYYYMMDD in SQL Server.

Comment: Indeed. The French language setting, to pick a common example, will interpret '2016-09-01 00:00:00' as 9th January 2016.

Answer (score -1):

In case you want time stamp also to be considered while evaluating your where condition, try converting your dates as:

```
CONVERT(datetime,'2016-09-01 00:00:00',101)
```

so you query would become:

```
select * from theTable 
where startDate between 
CONVERT(datetime,'2016-09-01 00:00:00',101) 
and 
CONVERT(datetime,'2016-09-08 23:59:59',101)
```

This way your month would be [9] instead of [1] and time stamp would also be considered.